# How to copy .so file from src to devel when catkin_make?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an external `.so` library to link. If I put it only in `src/lib/` and try to `find_library()` it, the `catkin_make` always fail. But if I manually put the `.so` file in `devel/lib/`, it works. Is there any way that I can automatically copy the `.so` file from `src/lib/` to `devel/lib/` ?

Here is a confusing thing. When I output the `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}`, it is the `src` folder, but when I use this address to `find_library`, it will be directed to `devel` folder. But I didn't put .so file in `devel/lib/`.

**My code in CMakeLists.txt:**

```
message("PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR: ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
find_library(DYNAMSOFT_LIBRARY 
  NAMES libDynamsoftBarcodeReader.so 
  PATHS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/)
message("DYNAMSOFT_LIBRARY: ${DYNAMSOFT_LIBRARY}")
```

**Corresponding output in terminal:**

```
PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR: /home/zhiyang/mfp_workspace/src/srsnode_barcode_reader
DYNAMSOFT_LIBRARY: /home/zhiyang/mfp_workspace/devel/lib/libDynamsoftBarcodeReader.so
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301152/how-to-copy-.so-file-from-src-to-devel-when-catkin_make?/) by [Crisliu7](https://answers.ros.org/users/37102/crisliu7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS package for the prosilica gige SDK does something similar: https://github.com/ros-drivers/prosilica_gige_sdk/blob/hydro-devel/CMakeLists.txt . It's a bit more complex because it's also packaging libraries for several different architectures and detecting the architecture at build time.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0